# What these simple rules of logical implications mean

Tags: logic, propositional-logic

Their are many rules of logics, predicate calculus, inferences and syllogisms which haunt me always. It feels better when I find some sensible name to particular rule which also gives me intuition about the meaning of the rule. Recently I came across some simple tautologies:

1. $((x \rightarrow y)\wedge(x \rightarrow \neg y))\rightarrow \neg x$
2. $((x \rightarrow y)\vee(x \rightarrow \neg y))$

I am struggling to find intuition or reasonable interpretation of their meaning:

1. Interpreting  rule 1:
   If a first variable $x$ implies both: second variable $y$ and its
   negation $\neg y$, then why the negation of first variable $\neg x$
   should always hold? Does it mean to imply that no such variable can
   exist which can imply both: another variable and its negation?
2. Interpreting  rule 2:
   Why should a first variable $x$ should always imply either (any
   given) second variable or its negation?
3. Finally are there any formal names used to refer these rules?

I must be missing something very basic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Contradictions can't happen. If $x$ implies a contradiction, then $x$ can't be true.
2. Either $y$ is true, or it isn't.  That's still the case even if I first tell you that $x$ is true.

Comment: If I am interpreting it correctly, I hope you mean the same (but in more precise manner) what I noted  in the question for point 1:  "no such variable can exist which can imply both: another variable and its negation". And by 2, can I interprete it as "conclusion is itself a standalone fact which does not need any other fact to hold for its existence" or "conclusion is not related to premise" ?

Answer (score 2):

As a terminological issue, "variables" don't imply things, propositions do.  Nor is it a good idea of thinking in terms of whether these propositions ("variables") can "exist" or not.  In this case you could say that $x$ and $y$ are [meta-variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metavariable) that stand for propositions. The rules you provided are rules that allow us to make inferences.  You can instantiate them with whatever propositions you like and they will be valid.  It can even be the case that you use the first rule to show that $\neg x$ but $x$ also holds.  In this case (assuming the logic is consistent), one of the assumptions must have been false which, incidentally, is exactly what the first rule is saying.

These two rules are slight variations of [non-contradiction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_noncontradiction) $\neg(P\land\neg P)$ and the [law of excluded middle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_excluded_middle) $P\lor\neg P$.  You are probably considering a [Hilbert-style proof system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_system) where it is common to formulate the rules as applying to implications to make up for the lack of the notion of context that other proof systems have.  In this case, these rules would likely just be called "non-contradiction" and "law of excluded middle" rather than having special names of their own.  There are many possible equivalent expressions and many possible equivalent axiomatizations, so most formulas won't have specific names. I'm not aware of names that would refer to these specific propositional formulas. It's possible they exist, but it wouldn't be very valuable to know them.

For 1, first note that $(P\to Q)\land(P \to R)$ is logically equivalent to $P \to (Q\land R)$<sup>1</sup>.  So the first interprets to "if $x$ implies a contradiction, then $x$ is false".  To connect it to my earlier statement, it says that if we assume $x$ and we can prove both $y$ and $\neg y$, i.e. a contradiction, then our assumption, namely $x$, must not hold.  In particular, non-contradiction, i.e. $\neg(P\land\neg P)$, intuitively states that a proposition can't be both true and false.

For 2, the underlying principle, the law of excluded middle, intuitively states that every proposition must be either true or false, there is no third<sup>2</sup> or "middle" option.  Like 1 you can show that $(P \to Q)\lor(P\to R)$ logically entails $P\to(Q\lor R)$<sup>3</sup>. This latter statement instantiated to the your second axiom then interprets as "any $x$ implies that either $y$ or $\neg y$ holds".  The former statement is a bit stronger and interprets as "either $y$ is true if $x$ is, or $y$ is false if $x$ is true".   Ultimately, $Q\lor R$ logically entails both of the earlier formulas, and if they hold for any proposition $P$, then they hold for a true proposition, e.g. $P\to P$, letting us derive $Q\lor R$ from that instance.  So as axiom *schemas* $(P\to Q)\lor(P \to\neg Q)$ and $P\to(Q\lor\neg Q)$ are equivalent assuming we have rules for manipulating implications and disjunctions. It's not unusual, though, in classical logic to choose a minimalistic set of axiom schemes that, while typically nicely symmetrical, are tightly interwoven which is why the stronger form may be necessary.

<sup>1</sup> This holds constructively.
<sup>2</sup> *tertium non datur*  "there is no third"
<sup>3</sup> Classically this is a logical equivalence, but constructively the converse doesn't hold.